# Output a table as well-formed, indented JSON

Tags: postgresql, backup, json, export

I have a table `dictionary` and its structure is:

```
create table dictionary
(
  id integer,
  first_level_key character varying(50),
  key_name character varying(50),
  key_value_en character varying(1000),
  key_value_fr character varying(1000)
);
```

I want to output this table as well-formed indented JSON.

I have tried the following query:

```
COPY (select 
   (select row_to_json(_) from (select c.first_level_key) as _) as first_last,
   c.key_name,c.key_name_value_en
from
   dictionary as c) 
 TO '/tmp/label_en.json';
```

I got JSON output, but not in the correct format, as shown below.

```
{"first_level_key":"topheader"} screen  Screen Reader Access
{"first_level_key":"header"}    title 
{"first_level_key":"header"}    subtitle 
{"first_level_key":"nav"}   about   About
```

The output that I want is well-formed, indented JSON as shown below!

```
{
"topheader":{

        "screen":"Screen Reader Access"
        },
        "header":{
        "title":"title",
        "subtitle":"subtitletest"
        },
    "nav":{
        "about":"About"
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query I'm using for getting the Json output. This may be help for other. 
[Here you could found the all steps](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=19072e103b8f79255252139492b50c82)

```
SELECT 
    jsonb_object_agg(key, value)
FROM (
    SELECT
        jsonb_build_object(first_level_key, jsonb_object_agg(key, value)) as language
    FROM (
          SELECT
                first_level_key,
                jsonb_build_object(first_level_key_name, key_value_en) AS first_level_key_name
            FROM
                dictionary
            GROUP BY first_level_key, first_level_key_name,key_value_en order by first_level_key desc
        ) s, 
        jsonb_each(first_level_key_name)

    GROUP BY first_level_key
) s,
jsonb_each(language)
```

Answer (score 1):

While rereading the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html), I noticed that whereas the `pretty_bool` option for `JSON` doesn't have an indented option, there is a `jsonb_pretty(from_json jsonb)` function which **does** produce indented text (`Returns from_json as indented JSON text.`) which looked as if it is what you are looking for.

When you have a "normal" table (I used your DDL in the question as my template), what you have to do is first convert it to `JSON` using the `ROW_TO_JSON` function ([documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html)), but as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20334221/470530) and elsewhere, this only converts the table to `JSON` on a row-by-row basis. The `JSONB_AGG` function (docs [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html)) `aggregates values, including nulls, as a JSON array`).

The final piece of the puzzle is the `JSONB_PRETTY` (discussed above) function which takes the `JSON` produced and outputs indented `JSON` text using your original query as the inner loop of the query.

Fiddle available [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a7563e200489146b30db05f9654634eb) (and all DDL and DML is at the bottom of this answer).

```
SELECT JSONB_PRETTY(JSONB_AGG(tab)) AS i_json FROM
(
  SELECT
  ( 
    SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(x) 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT c.first_level_key) AS x
    ) AS first_last,
    c.key_name, c.key_value_en
  FROM
  dictionary AS c
) AS tab;
```

Sample output (entire table at end of this answer):

```
[
    {
        "key_name": "ttttttt",
        "first_last": {
            "first_level_key": "afasaffasa"
        },
        "key_value_en": "zxccc"
    },
```

I believe that this is (finally!) the correct answer!

When asking a question, please **always** provide your version - it can be very important for providing an answer.

DDL and DML (also on the fiddle):

Create table. Note that I used the `TEXT` datatype instead of `VARCHAR(n)` for reasons discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20326892/any-downsides-of-using-data-type-text-for-storing-strings/20334221#20334221) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848964/postgresql-difference-between-text-and-varchar-character-varying).

```
CREATE TABLE dictionary
(
  id INTEGER,
  first_level_key TEXT,
  key_name TEXT,
  key_value_en TEXT,
  key_value_fr TEXT
);
```

Populate it:

```
INSERT INTO dictionary 
VALUES 
(4, 'afasaffasa', 'ttttttt', 'zxccc', 'zzzzzzz'),
(4, 'afasawweww', 'rrrrrrr', 'zxccc', 'zzzzzzz'),
(4, 'afayyyyyyy', 'eeeeeee', 'zxccc', 'zzzzzzz'),
(4, 'xxxxxxxxxx', 'wwwwwww', 'zxccc', 'zzzzzzz'),
(4, 'mmmmmmmmmm', 'qqqqqqq', 'zxccc', 'zzzzzzz');
```

Run query:

```
SELECT JSONB_PRETTY(JSONB_AGG(tab)) AS i_json FROM
(
  SELECT
  ( 
    SELECT ROW_TO_JSON(x) 
    FROM 
    (
      SELECT c.first_level_key) AS x
    ) AS first_last,
    c.key_name, c.key_value_en
  FROM
  dictionary AS c
) AS tab;
```

Result:

```
i_json
[
    {
        "key_name": "ttttttt",
        "first_last": {
            "first_level_key": "afasaffasa"
        },
        "key_value_en": "zxccc"
    },
    {
        "key_name": "rrrrrrr",
        "first_last": {
            "first_level_key": "afasawweww"
        },
        "key_value_en": "zxccc"
    },
    {
        "key_name": "eeeeeee",
        "first_last": {
            "first_level_key": "afayyyyyyy"
        },
        "key_value_en": "zxccc"
    },
    {
        "key_name": "wwwwwww",
        "first_last": {
            "first_level_key": "xxxxxxxxxx"
        },
        "key_value_en": "zxccc"
    },
    {
        "key_name": "qqqqqqq",
        "first_last": {
            "first_level_key": "mmmmmmmmmm"
        },
        "key_value_en": "zxccc"
    }
]
```

Comment: It is not coming as correct formate as you have created you could see the  Json key_name always coming` "key_name": "wwwwwww",` inside of name we need values like this `{
"topheader":{

        "screen":"Screen Reader Access"
        },
        "header":{
        "title":"title",
        "subtitle":"subtitletest"
        },
    "nav":{
        "about":"About"
}}`

Comment: Is something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b0faf5c5405af818c2b015bdaaa2d509) more what you're looking for?

Comment: Is something like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b0faf5c5405af818c2b015bdaaa2d509) more what you're looking for? If not, can you provide some sample data in the form of DML?

Comment: Lots of  Thanks for your valuable time (https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b0faf5c5405af818c2b015bdaaa2d509) in this Json output  having all ` "ttttttt":`

Comment: Mr. @Verace please check this query  [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=abf0a9abc0643b2c43a1fd3817f8c04e) I have briefly explain the Json output should be in the formate

Comment: Ah, OK - this clearly demonstrates the value of using a fiddle with a sample of data and a clear outline of your desired result. I'll take a look later to see what I can come up with!

Comment: sure Mr. @Verace

Answer (score 0):

> The output that I want is well-formed, indented JSON

- *Well-formed* JSON is what you get from the function you're already using, by which I mean "some text" that it syntactically valid *as* JSON.
- *Indented* JSON is something that is "pretty" and human-readable.

I have to ask *why* you feel the need for the latter?

JSON is a Data Transfer medium.
As such, I would not expect "average" Users to be interacting with it directly, so why should any JSON data need to be "bloated out" with all that redundant and processing time-consuming white-space that the format *itself* has no use for?

Comment: You might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12943819/how-to-prettyprint-a-json-file/12944035#12944035) - an answer (Python) on more or less the same topic as the above - it has **1561** upvotes - so, obviously people **are** interested in producing human-readable `JSON`!  I just hope my answer gets that many upvotes! :-)

Comment: yes you are right Mr. @Vérace the answer is given by Mr. Andy (6th) answer is very close enough

Comment: If you've managed to translate the Python into SQL and obtained the result you want, then please post that code here - I, for one, will upvote that answer! :-) p.s. calling any answer the "6th" one can be tricky - answers can move up or down depending on votes - the poster's name should be enough!